# Difference theme legend position and show.legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am studying `ggplot2` Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis.
What difference both code are?

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  directlabels::geom_dl(aes(label = class), method = "smart.grid")


ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  directlabels::geom_dl(aes(label = class), method = "smart.grid")
```

both create this plot

[image]

I wonder when I use `show.legend = FALSE`

Comment: What do you mean? There is no difference. Both `ggplot` commands are identical.

Comment: Sorry, I edit it. I mean that In this case, I think both code is same but when use `show.legend = FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?geom_point`

> show.legend: logical. Should this layer be included in the legends?
>             ‘NA’, the default, includes if any aesthetics are mapped.
>             ‘FALSE’ never includes, and ‘TRUE’ always includes. It can
>             also be a named logical vector to finely select the
>             aesthetics to display.

From `?theme`

> legend.position: the position of legends ("none", "left", "right",
>             "bottom", "top", or two-element numeric vector)

`theme(legend.position = "none")` disables *all* legends, `geom_point(..., show.legends = FALSE)` disables the legend for this (i.e. the `geom_point`) layer.

---

For example

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_label(aes(label = class)) + 
  directlabels::geom_dl(aes(label = class), method = "smart.grid")
```

shows no legend for `geom_point`, but does show a legend for `geom_label`.

[image]

---

On the other hand,

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(label = class)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  directlabels::geom_dl(aes(label = class), method = "smart.grid")
```

disables all legends.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: No worries @0Hong; glad to help.